# Oracle Update and select in a single query

Tags: oracle

I'm working with a vendor's database, and I need to increment a value and return it. I have the right command, it updates the table, but the output in oracle developer just says "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." How do I return NewReceiptNumber?

```
DECLARE
   NewReceiptNumber int;
BEGIN
    UPDATE SYSCODES 
    SET (VAR_VALUE) = VAR_VALUE+1
    WHERE VAR_NAME='LAST_RCPT'
    RETURNING VAR_VALUE INTO NewReceiptNumber;
END;
```

Comment: Begin a transaction, do your update, do a select, then commit your changes. Since this is Oracle, You may not have to do the begin tran since it is implied.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - does your vendor not already provide an API to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just depicting an anonymous block there, to VIEW the value of `NewReceiptNumber` in that code you'll have to use:

`dbms_output.put_line(NewReceiptNumber)`.

as in:

```
DECLARE
   NewReceiptNumber int;
BEGIN
    UPDATE SYSCODES 
    SET (VAR_VALUE) = VAR_VALUE+1
    WHERE VAR_NAME='LAST_RCPT'
    RETURNING VAR_VALUE INTO NewReceiptNumber;

    dbms_output.put_line(NewReceiptNumber);
END;
```

But if your intention is to actually return this value to another procedure or a call from your front-end, you'll have to declare a stored procedure and within that declaration indicate your output parameter, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc(newreceiptnumber out INT) AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE syscodes 
    SET (var_value) = var_value+1
    WHERE var_name='LAST_RCPT'
    RETURNING var_value INTO newreceiptnumber;
END my_proc;
```

And of course it'll be a more robust solution if you send your updated values as parameters as well, this is just the minimal approach.

Comment: Do I have any options if I don't have permissions to create a stored proc?

Comment: Yes you have, but please be more specific about what you want to accomplish, so we can provide a more ad hoc answer.

Comment: Sorry, I need to do as you say, return the new receipt number for a front end to supply a user on a webpage.

Comment: Usually it's not a good practice, but you could code your update sentence within your front end application. Depending on your developing language, some allow to bind a value from your hard-coded sentence to a container, something like `"UPDATE syscodes set (var_value) = var_value+1 WHERE var_name= 'LAST_RCPT' RETURNING var_value INTO ? "`  and that "?"  symbol can be binded and stored in a local variable in your code.

Comment: Contacted them and got stored proc access, so this worked out perfect. Thank you.